# ls -Xmx memory limit for Intellij IDEA shared between open project windows?

Tags: memory, intellij-idea, shared-memory, heap-memory

Intellij IDEA memory settings may be [customized](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) by editing `-Xmx` option at `idea64.vmoptions`. Let's say, I set

```
-Xmx2g
```

and then open 5 different projects at the same time. Can IDEA eventually consume up to ~10gb of memory, or it will be limited to 2gb+some overhead?

At memory usage monitor in the lower right corner of IDEA window, I see the different value of allocated memory for each project. On the other hand, these values seem to correlate over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same single process running in the same JVM, so the limit is for all the windows/projects.

Comment: Thanks. That was somewhat counter-intuitive for me